# Rendering XML with bigger content

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

The CF application returns an XML response to a desktop application. XML response is alright within .5 to 3 seconds. XML contain attachments which are zipped and then base64 encoded. As soon as we have attachment slightly bigger, say 5MB it starts to take more than a minute for response. Not the real code, but that is what I am doing (CF2016 & IIS):

```
<cfxml variable="myXML">    
<sample Status="NewJob" Type="response">
<NewJob>
   <jobNumber>3894743</jobNumber>
   <Rate>0</Rate>
   <doc><![CDATA[UEsDBBQACAAIAMl BASE_64_CONTENT]]></doc>
 </NewJob>
</sample>
</cfxml>
<cfset tempVar = xmlParse(trim(myXML))>
<cfcontent type="text/xml">
<cfoutput>#TempVar#</cfoutput>
```

Though files are zipped but sometimes compression is not big and 8MB file is about 7MB after compression. Total page weight become around 9MB+

Can increasing Maximum output buffer from 1024kb to 4096KB or even 2048kb help? Any consequences for doing that? Any other setting on CF or IIS which can be tweaked?

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using `xmlParse()`? The `<cfxml>` tag already produces a XML document. Right now, your code stringifies the XML document (argument of `xmlParse`), then parses it as XML document (return of `xmlParse`) and then stringifies it again (outputting `TempVar`). Simplify your code:

```
<cfxml variable="myXML">
    <sample Status="NewJob" Type="response">
        <NewJob>
            <jobNumber>3894743</jobNumber>
            <Rate>0</Rate>
            <doc><![CDATA[UEsDBBQACAAIAMl BASE_64_CONTENT]]></doc>
        </NewJob>
    </sample>
</cfxml>

<cfcontent type="text/xml">
<cfoutput>#myXML#</cfoutput>
```

Now your XML document is only stringified once and without any parsing. This should speed up the processing noticeably.

Comment: Thanks fro pointing that out. But it did not made any change. Still taking the similar time.